ChromeDriver - element can be located on Chrome v125 but not on v126
I have a C# Selenium test that fails to locate an element on Chrome v126. This works fine on Chrome v125, and using the same CSS selector on Chrome v126 browser console works fine. Has anyone encountered the same and have any solution to overcome this?
I find that using JavascriptExecutor and having window.document.getElementsByClassName('saveTransaction')[0].click() works fine on click operations, but that means I need to convert everything into that way of working through elements. It proves that the element exists in DOM, but somehow my code can't find it on Chrome v126.
window.document.getElementsByClassName('saveTransaction')[0].click() works fine, using "$$" on Chrome v126 console properly identifies the element using my CSS selector.
//Initialize the driver as how you would normally do with ChromeOptions
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.BrowserVersion = BrowserVersion;
webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri($"http://{GridMachine}:4444/wd/hub"), chromeOptions);

//What doesn't work
webDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("saveTransaction")).Click();

//The code below throws NoSuchElementException
var x = webDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("saveTransaction")).Displayed;

//What works fine
var js = webDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("window.document.getElementsByClassName(\"saveTransaction\")[0].click()");


Can you [edit] your question to include a [repro]? Selenium is tricky. The line that throws an exception might not be the line you need to fix.

Thanks for reviewing @GregBurghardt. I have provided a sample code above.

After days of fiddling, I found a workaround. While this solution isn't required to be in place when running the test on Chrome v125, this works well for Chrome v126.
var hnd = webDriver.WindowHandles;

//Update the code below depending on how many window handles you have.
webDriver.SwitchTo().Window(hnd[0]);

You need the code above before you perform your element interactions (find elements, clicks, etc.).
